# How do I change bootable device?

Tags: 16.04

I made my usb pen drive the bootable device and the hard drive is the ejectable one. it wants to install a new Ubuntu everytime i switch it on and it forgets everything that I’ve done previously as well. Also I’m trying to run 16.04

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as asked:  Your BIOS is set to boot from the USB drive before the hard drive.  To change the bootable device, go into BIOS and set it to boot the hard drive first.

---

Note that after you have used the USB to do the installation on the hard drive it tells you to remove the installation media before it reboots into the new system.  So at that point you can just remove the USB install media and it will boot from the hard drive as long as your BIOS has it next in the boot device sequence.

Comment: Didn’t work I changed the bios so that everything usb related was at the bottom,  installed it again, took the usb out shut it down and powered it back on for it to say ‘no bootable device’

Comment: Sounds like you haven't done the installation.  Thus, the hard drive is not bootable.